# URL Rewriting (Internal/External Forwarders) .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using .htaccess for URL Rewriting. My current .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile\.php\?profil=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ fr/profil-des-transporteurs/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^fr/profil-des-transporteurs/([^/.]+)/?$ fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile.php?profil=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

My URL is :

```
https://example.com/fr/profil-des-transporteurs/1927
```

It works fine when I place .htaccess file in DOCUMENT_ROOT directory.

But it doesnot work when I put same .htaccess file in real sub-directory i.e /fr/.

So what should I do, if I want to place .htaccess file in sub-directory i.e /fr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these rules inside `/fr/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fr/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile\.php\?profil=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profil-des-transporteurs/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^profil-des-transporteurs/([^/.]+)/?$ transporter/transporterPublicProfile.php?profil=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: it redirects to https://example.com/profil-des-transporteurs/1927 it must b redirect to https://example.com/fr/profil-des-transporteurs/1927

Comment: Are you sure you have `RewriteBase /fr/` and then `RewriteRule ^ profil-des-transporteurs/%1? [R=302,L,NE]`?

Comment: You can try first rule as: `RewriteRule ^ /fr/profil-des-transporteurs/%1? [R=302,L,NE]`

Comment: yes this works fine for me .


RewriteBase /fr/
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile\.php\?profil=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ fr/profil-des-transporteurs/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^profil-des-transporteurs/([^/.]+)/?$ fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile.php?profil=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fr
```